# PHP page taking forever to reload after a call to mail()

Tags: php, email

I am trying to implement simple email verification in PHP when a user registers. I have most of everything working but am running into problems when using the mail function.

I have a form which sends data over POST to the same php page (index.php). The form is submitting the information correctly, the page is receiving the information correctly. When I include the call to mail() the email sends correctly and ends up in my inbox, however it makes the page hang (chrome's dev tools says its pending) for 1 minute before reloading.

Here is the relevant code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['reguser']) && !empty($_POST['regpass'])) {

  $username = $userConn->real_escape_string($_POST['reguser']);
  $password = password_hash($userConn->real_escape_string($_POST['regpass']), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $email =  $userConn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."'";
  $uniqueResult = $userConn->query($sql);

  if ($uniqueResult->num_rows == 1) {
    echo "Name already taken";
  } else {
    $registerSQL = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress, ActivationHash) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."', '".$hash."')";
    $registerResult = $userConn->query($registerSQL);

    if ($registerResult) {

      $to = $email;
      $subject = 'Website| Verification';
      $message = '
      You have successfully signed up for Website!<br /><br />

      To activate your account please <a href="http://Website.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'">click here</a> or paste the following link into your browser bar:<br /><br />

      http://Website.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'
      <br /><br />
      Thanks!
      ';

      $headers = 'From: noreply@website.com' . "\r\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
      echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='=2;index.php' />";

    } else {
      echo "Registration failed";
    }
  }
}
```

When I inspect the page using the dev tools it tells me that the page takes exactly one minute to reload, so my guess is its timing out. However, the mail does still successfully to the desired address.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Suggest looking in to PHP [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.addtaskbackground.php) or passing the request off to Curl in order to send the email. Alternatively, look at the configuration of the email server you are using (if you can). I'm guessing there are some anti-spam settings that are creating that delay or lack of return message (hence the timeout).

Comment: Firstly, please avoid using PHP's built-in `mail()` function. It is severely limited in capabilities. As soon as you start building mail headers manually in your code you should be thinking of using a pre-built library like phpMailer or Swiftmailer. Secondly, I recommend using a third party mail provider to actually deliver the mail rather than your web server; this will move any processing delays away from your front-end. (note that `mail()` function can't do this, but phpMailer/Swiftmailer can, so another good reason to use them). For the mail delivery you could use Gmail, or many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use mail queue instead of sending email immediately. Once new user has created add record to mail queue table. Use separate cron PHP script to send emails using records from mail queue table.